# Swapping randomly between two lists in python

Tags: python, list, random, swap, shuffle

I have two lists of strings, each has 260 element. I want to mix 100 items randomly between the the two lists . the 100 I want randomly without giving specific range since I am going to do that at 100 cycles.

for example : if list `a` is `[x1,x2,x3..,x260]` and `b` is `[y1,y2,y3..',y260]`

output : a `[x1,y3,y5,..]`  b `[y1,y2,x5..]`.

I thought to do that with shuffling but didn't know if it is possible to do random shuffling without giving a range with only a number of items

Comment: sounds like a home work to me. What's your question? How far you have coded so far?

Comment: i think you want to swap elements by preserved positions? if yes: i would use a index list [0, ..., 260] which is a pool to randomly pop out element by element (100 times). this popped elements are the index of swapping elements of your lists.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```py
import random

def get_mixed_result(a: list, b: list) -> list:
    items = []
    both_lists = [a, b]
    for i in range(100):
         selected_list = random.choice(both_lists)
         selected_item = random.choice(selected_list)
         items.append(selected_item)
    return items
```